# publish / rollout options for different versions / customizations of the same application to different customers?

Tags: android, google-play, publish, rollout

Current issue: 
How do we efficiently deploy different versions of the same App to different customers?

Example:

App version 1.1 needs to be installed for customer A.

App version 1.2 needs to be installed for customer B.

App version 1.3 needs to be installed for customer C.

App versions 1.1, 1.2 and 1.3 are basically the same application with small differences between them (probably different backend versions required). Some features might be missing or might be extra on some versions depending on customers explicitly wanting them or not, or the branding might be different: different logo, different theme etc. It is basically the same codebase but with variations specifically asked by the clients.

We need a way to publish the app and indicate to our customers which app version they need to install. What options do we have?

I have researched using the following documentation:
https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/index.html
https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/alternative-distribution

I would really appreciated an answer from someone who dealt with this kind of situation before.

Comment: The most straight-forward solution that comes to mind would be roll out 1.1 as a normal production release, 1.2 as a beta, and 1.3 as an alpha. Of course this setup only works when you have at most 3 different variants, and it doesn't support e.g. hiding version 1.1 from those users that are supposed to run version 1.2 or 1.3. I'm not familiar with any other methods of limiting rollouts to specific users.

Comment: Hi Michael, this solution does not work for us - as we roll out to more and more customers the number of versions might increase. Plus, it is not best practice to roll out application the way you described.